# Who generates JWT when using Google OpenID Connect authnentication for my ASP.NET Core Web API app?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, asp.net-core-webapi

I am building an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API application for mobile clients (and maybe later SPA JS app). The application should have sign-in with Google option. I also want to add my own app's custom sign up and sign in options that would also be based on JWT authentication and not cookie.

I understand that for my custom sign in flow my app will generated JWT that will be sent to the client.
But I have few questions how that works when user signs-in with its Google account:

1. who's responsibility is to generate the JWT when user signs-in with its Google account? Is that responsibility of Google or mine application? I don't want Google to return JWT to the client in the cookie.
2. Then when client is authenticated with Google, and sends requests to my application, how can my application validate JWT token it gets?
3. When user signs in with Google for the first time, should I automatically register that user in my application (I am using Identity framework) by taking claim values (email) from the JWT? What is the general practice here?

I am trying to understand these processes and flows so sample code is not necessary (but I do welcome it).

Answer (score 1):

Ad.1. Normally, in a larger system, you would have an authorization server (AS) that would handle user authentication and the issuance of tokens. Your clients would contact only the AS, and the AS will be able to provide the user with different forms of authentication: e.g., through your website's password or through Google. The AS is the single point of issuing tokens to your clients. It can issue tokens regardless of the authentication method used. So it then doesn't matter whether the user authenticated with Google or a password, the client will still get the same access token.

Ad.2. When the AS issues token to your client, then you don't have any problems validating that token. The client doesn't care if the user authenticated with Google or not, it's not relevant in this case.

If you decide to skip using an AS and let the client receive tokens directly from Google, then you can still verify them. An ID token is a JWT and can be easily validated with a JWT library using verification keys provided by Google. Access tokens returned by Google are opaque tokens (If I remember correctly), and you need to check whether Google exposes an endpoint to verify them.

Ad.3. That is the general practice. When the user authenticates with Google and you notice that you don't have that user's data in your system, then you take the information from Google's ID token and create a user entry in your system.